# How to do WHERE <before> an aggregate function (Postgres)

Tags: database, postgresql

It's hard to explain from the title, but this is my SQL:

```
SELECT
  SUM("payments"."amount"),
  "invoices"."property_id"
FROM "payments"
JOIN "invoices"
  ON "payments"."invoice_id" = "invoices"."id"
GROUP BY "property_id"
```

It returns the sum of all `Payment` records (`amount` column) for a particular `Property` (which is connected through it's invoices).

In other words:

```
Property has_many: :invoices
Invoice has_one: :payment
```

I'm trying to select payments between a particular date range though, but it has to happen "before" the aggregate function (so do the exact query above, but only for 2017-01-01 through 2017-02-01). The field would be `generated_at` on `Payment`

Comment: The WHERE clause is executed before aggregation.

Comment: Damn really...? I am a moron

Comment: I didn't even try that, I just assumed that wouldnt work... doh!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a `WHERE` clause. (`WHERE` is executed before aggregation; `HAVING` is executed after.) Suggested date literals in PostgreSQL are ANSI standard `DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'`. Date ranges are usually checked with >= start day and < end day + 1 (in order to deal properly with the time part if any).

```
SELECT
  SUM(p.amount),
  i.property_id
FROM payments p
JOIN invoices i ON p.invoice_id = i.id
WHERE p.generated_at >= DATE '2017-01-01' 
  AND p.generated_at < DATE '2017-02-02'
GROUP BY i.property_id;
```

Comment: dates don't have a time part

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: How do you know generated_at's data type? It isn't mentioned anywhere.